# Windows Phone app - How to make a threaded Tcp Client

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, tcpclient

I want to make a windows phone app that can connect to my TCP server and be able to read many data it receives from  my server asynchronously. I cannot find any clear examples online of how to get my client app to connect to the server and read data sent by the server. The windows Samples helped me a bit, but i was wondering if anyone can find any other sources or examples online that might help me with this project.

I would REALLY appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use HTTP rather than bare sockets, here's a starting place describing async /await pattern for web requests (and other APIs).

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/vstudio/hh191443(v=vs.110).aspx
```

Or you can open a NetworkStream,

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.aspx
```

then use async methods with a regular StreamReader.

If all else fails, you can use the bare sockets async calls:

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.receivefromasync.aspx
```

but those don't use the shiny new async / await keyword; it's more like handling events from a control.

Comment: You can trivially use `TaskFactory.FromAsync()` [(msdn ref)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.fromasync.aspx) to create an awaitable object from the BeginRecieveFrom/EndRecieveFrom pair on the socket.

Comment: @BobHy the second link is for .NET framework. NetworkStream class is not part of windows phone.